# Simple License Manager in Joomla Extensions?

Tags: joomla, licensing, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

we run a Joomla Extensions store. We are looking to make it subscription based, so users can download multiple files instead of buying single files, as they do now.

But in that case, I want to restrict the number of domains the users install it on.

For example, lets say, one user as SILVER membership and that membership only allows 3 DOMAINS usage. Means, whenever he installs it on any site, the extension should not work , unless he enters the license code generated from our website. And once the 3 licenses are created by him , the next time he installs the extension somewhere, an automatic email should come to me that an unauthorized usage was done, and the extension should not work at all.

Whereever activated, it should show, PLEASE ENTER LICENSE CODE.

So, how do we handle this ?

Comment: Very good question. It would definitely come in handy for a lot of extension developers.

Comment: Joomla is GPL, you most likely violate the terms of use when you distribute derivative works in a way to prevent access to the source-code under terms of the GPL.

Comment: I don't think this extension will be published in Joomla as they take these things very seriously. You can make it a paid component with three domain support. But without license if an extension stops working that goes against GPL.

Comment: @hakre There's nothing stopping you from releasing closed source components, they just wont get published on the JED.

Comment: @AdamB: Well, it's not so comfortable for customers going into copyright violation because the person releasing closed is doing a copyright violation. Therefore ... .

Comment: @hakre it does not violate Joomla's terms. I have used such components myself in the past like JReviews. It only violates the Joomla Extensions Directory's terms which is why they aren't listed. It is in any case not a copyright violation of any kind and perfectly legal.

Comment: @AdamB: Not for you personally probably, but ship it to clients and things can turn out different quickly. As the Joomla Directory is for distribution, I have the feeling that's exactly the reason why they have such terms.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you shall use any encryption and and while the component runs it should compare the license key on the fly.

the license key will be given from your end and the key can be compared with same logic implemented with the key generation

Seller side:
Generate a encyption Key (logic : their email id with userid or domain name they have purchased any feasible idea)

give this to the customer

Customer (Component)

get the email id with user id or any logic used and generate encryption and compare on the fly

here we are not storing any key so it will be safer and the code is not encryptped and genuine buyers will care care for the license key and purchase.

as long as you keep the logic safer it will work ;)

it will not violate the JED rules